# How to display data from database table independently

Tags: php, mysql

Problem desc.

I have databese called demo. In this databse i have columns. Two of them are otk and zamestnanci.

```
/*zamestnanci = employees*/
```

So i have some data in otk table:

```
/*otk columns: id_otk|ciarovy_kod|cislo_zakazky|zamestnanci|*/
/*id_otk = autoincrement*/
/*zamestnanci can be only number*/

INSERT INTO otk (ciarovy_kod, cislo_zakazky, zamestnanci) VALUES ('65464', '564', '1');
```

And now i have some data in zamestnanci:

```
/*zamestnanci columns: id_zamestnanci|titul|meno|titulz|*/
/*id_zamestnanci = autoincrement*/

INSERT INTO zamestnanci (titul, meno, titulz) VALUES ('ads', 'John', 'das');
```

And now here is my code for displaing and searching data from otk:

```
if(isset($_GET['hladat']))
{
    $hladatHodnotu = $_GET['hladatHodnotu'];
    // hladat v setkych stlpcoch
    // pouzitie concat funkcie pre vyhladanie iba urciteho stlpca
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM otk JOIN zamestnanci ON zamestnanci.id_zamestnanci=otk.zamestnanci
                              JOIN zariadenia ON zariadenia.id=otk.zariadenie
                              JOIN stav ON stav.id=otk.stav
                              JOIN technologie ON technologie.id=otk.technologie
                              JOIN obrazky ON obrazky.id_obrazky=otk.obrazok 
                              WHERE CONCAT(`ciarovy_kod`) LIKE '%".$hladatHodnotu."%'";
    $vysledokHladania = filtrovatTabulku($sql);

}

//Zobrazovanie dat z viacerych tabuliek do jednej
/*                            JOIN zamestnanci ON zamestnanci.id_zamestnanci=otk.zamestnanci 
                              JOIN zariadenia ON zariadenia.id=otk.zariadenie
                              JOIN stav ON stav.id=otk.stav
                              JOIN technologie ON technologie.id=otk.technologie
                              JOIN obrazky ON obrazky.id_obrazky=otk.obrazok*/
 else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM otk JOIN zamestnanci ON zamestnanci.id_zamestnanci=otk.zamestnanci
                              JOIN zariadenia ON zariadenia.id=otk.zariadenie
                              JOIN stav ON stav.id=otk.stav
                              JOIN technologie ON technologie.id=otk.technologie
                              JOIN obrazky ON obrazky.id_obrazky=otk.obrazok";

    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM zariadenia, otk WHERE zariadenia.id=otk.zariadenie";
    $vysledokHladania = filtrovatTabulku($sql);
}

// funkcia na pripojenie a spustenie $sql
function filtrovatTabulku($sql)
{
    //Zahrnut pripojenie k db
    include'../db/dbinfo.php';
    $vysledokHladania = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    return $vysledokHladania;
}
```

And now when i empty table "zamestnanci" it will not display data from "otk" with id of that "zamestnanci" because he do not exist. So i want to ask you if there is way how to display if "zamestnanci" is not exist.

Comment: You should be using something to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Please read about why using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding" is important.

Comment: you can use a left join that will show a NULL for data existing in the first table and not in the second

Comment: I know this is not secured. It is only testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong `JOIN`. 
You should learn how each join works before using them, read more about them here http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/